# Is there "operator overloading" in ES6 / TypeScript? (or how to make object invokable)

Tags: javascript, typescript, operator-overloading, invoke

I've been away from JS development for some time and wonder if there is something like this in modern JavaScript or TypeScript?

C++

```
struct Functor {
    double operator()(double value) { ... }
```

Kotlin:

```
class Whatever {
    operator fun invoke(value: Double): Double { ... }
```

In ES5 it was possible to do:

```
var interpolator = function (value) {
    var t = (value - domainStart) / domainDelta
    return (1 - t) * rangeStart + t * rangeEnd;
}
interpolator.invert = function () { ... }
interpolator.setDomain = function (a, b) { ... }
interpolator.setRange = function (a, b) { ... }

// and then use like so
interpolator.setDomain(0, 1)
interpolator.setRange(50, 200)
let rangeValue = interpolator(0.5) // 125
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formal overloading of the `()` operator, but the `ES5` technique works fine in modern JS as well.

As far as the Typescript story on this, your code works almost as is in Typescript 3.1

```
function interpolator(value: number) {
    return value
}
interpolator.invert = function () {  }
interpolator.setDomain = function (a : number, b: number) {  }
interpolator.setRange = function (a: number, b: number) {  }

// and the use like so
interpolator.setDomain(0, 1)
interpolator.setRange(50, 200)
let rangeValue = interpolator(0.5) // 125);
```

[Playgrounk link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20interpolator(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterpolator.invert%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0Ainterpolator.setDomain%20%3D%20function%20(a%20%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0Ainterpolator.setRange%20%3D%20function%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20the%20use%20like%20so%0D%0Ainterpolator.setDomain(0%2C%201)%0D%0Ainterpolator.setRange(50%2C%20200)%0D%0Alet%20rangeValue%20%3D%20interpolator(0.5)%20%2F%2F%20125)%3B)

This is due to the new feature in 3.1 called [Property assignments on function declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368).

Before 3.1 you need an extra namespace to achieve a properly typed function with extra members

```
function interpolator(value: number) {
    return value
}
namespace interpolator {
    export function invert() { }
    export function setDomain(a: number, b: number) { }
    export function setRange (a: number, b: number) { }
}

// and the use like so
interpolator.setDomain(0, 1)
interpolator.setRange(50, 200)
let rangeValue = interpolator(0.5) // 125);
```

[Playgrounk link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20interpolator(value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20interpolator%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20invert()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20setDomain(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20setRange%20(a%3A%20number%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20the%20use%20like%20so%0D%0Ainterpolator.setDomain(0%2C%201)%0D%0Ainterpolator.setRange(50%2C%20200)%0D%0Alet%20rangeValue%20%3D%20interpolator(0.5)%20%2F%2F%20125)%3B)

Comment: @Vitaly yes, the question is very timely :) I added the legacy way to do it (ie before 3.1 when we had to write code like animals :P)